# Access specific row data on FlatList - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I'm making an api request, rendering results using FlatList like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity  onPress={this._onPressButton}>

<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity 
        activeOpacity={0.8} 
        onPress=this._onPressButton}>
                <ListItem
                        title= {`${item.companyName}`}
                        subtitle= {`[ ${item.symbol} ] ${item.change}%`}
                />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

my goal is to access data on specific rows, let's suppose I created a function that make an alert:

```
  _onPressButton = () => {
    alert('What should search for here?')
  };
```

How to access `item.companyName` ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the outer `TouchableOpacity`.

Comment: @joshua-r Making another api request using companyName and navigating to another screen, but I don't know how do I get this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

```
<FlatList
data={this.state.data}
renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity 
    activeOpacity={0.8} 
    onPress={()=>this._onPressButton(item.companyName)}>
            <ListItem
                    title= {item.companyName}
                    subtitle= {`[ ${item.symbol} ] ${item.change}%`}
            />
```

with

```
_onPressButton = (companyName) => {alert(companyName)};
```